# Specific cast not valid

Tags: .net, vb.net, linq-to-sql

I use Linq-to-SQL to insert data in vb.net. When I insert data into SQL Server through a DataGridView it gives error of which column data type is "integer" but when I insert data through textbox it not give any error

So I face problem of datatype "integer" to error of specific cast not valid

Comment: show the code to have good answers.

Comment: Can you post the offending code?

Comment: Looks like an issue with String to Int conversion. Can you post the Model and the code you are using?

Answer (score 2):

Well,

There are a few ways to convert a string to an int. But for a safe conversion I would go int.TryParse(your_string_value, out result_value)

This will give you the chance to handle none int values in a more graceful manner.

Good Luck

Answer (score 0):

Try using `CType`

```
someObject.IntegerProperty = CType(myTextBox.Value, Int32)
```

---

[CType Function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4x2877xb.aspx#Y500)

> Returns the result of explicitly converting an expression to a specified data type, object, structure, class, or interface.

Comment: for VB, I would choose CInt over CType, but would agree with @Reactor's recommendation of Integer.TryParse over both of these for user supplied input values.

Comment: @JimWooley: There is also `Convert.ToIn32(...)` function.

Comment: @neolisk, but does Convert.ToInt32 handle nulls without throwing an exception?

Comment: @JimWooley: Yes, you get 0 (default value for the type, in most generic case, I'd assume). Confirmed just now in VS 2010.